# If a radar chart values are full it occupies half the space (Chart.js)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, radar-chart

I created a radar chart that has full values, but if its full, the area occupied is 50%, any way to fix that? (even if that is as designed).

https://codepen.io/asaadmahmood/pen/XWgrGWg

```html
<canvas id="marksChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
```

```js
var marksCanvas = document.getElementById("marksChart");

var marksData = {
  labels: ["English", "Maths", "Physics", "Chemistry", "Biology", "History"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "Student A",
    backgroundColor: "rgba(200,0,0,0.2)",
    data: [100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100]
  }]
};

var radarChart = new Chart(marksCanvas, {
  type: 'radar',
  data: marksData
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, need to set:

```
scales: {
    r: {
        beginAtZero: true,
    }
}
```